# Tasks and operators order in airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have a dag with operator and two tasks. I can't understand how to make tasks and operators linear.

- I *expected* to have scheme like **FIRST -> SECOND -> THIRD**
- But have **FIRST and SECOND in parallel and after THIRD**

My code:

```
first = MyOwnOperator(
    task_id='first',
)

@task()
def second():
    return 'some value to third task'

@task()
def third(key: str):
    print('value from previous task', key)

first >> third(second())
```

Could you please tell any ideas how to make it?

I want to find more readable solution than `first >> second >> third` with `xcom_pull`.

Comment: There's nothing here that would prevent `first` and `second` from running in parallel.  All you said was that `third` depends on `first`.

Comment: @TimRoberts yes, in this example I don't have but in my real case I have some initialization in `first` operator so it's important to have linear order. And my `third` task depends on `second` task result

Comment: Then don't you want `first >> second >> third`?

Comment: [link to scheme I want](https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipOrPBUgNdPxYAd6WMZYuKSll7rru2avkVr6YX8BoYH4FvH06O4AalebJGkwRxydjw?key=M2JaQmRpTWdIUFZyWklOalhqZmFTdWZ1cFRXUXFB)

Comment: Isn't that exactly what I just said?

Comment: @TimRoberts Yes, but my `third` task have an argument - returned value from `second` task. That's why `first >> second >> third` don't work for me. I know that I could use methods like xcom_pull from context of `third` task but I want to find more readable solution

Comment: Then you need XComs.  https://docs.astronomer.io/learn/airflow-passing-data-between-tasks

Comment: But, if those three things have to run serially, what's the point in turning them into tasks?  Why not just have one task that runs the three functions in order?

Comment: @Tim Roberts, if you merge tasks into one, you cannot reuse them separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this using a temporary variable.

```
second_ret = second()
first >> second_ret
third(second_ret)
```

It will be prettier, if you add a dummy argument to the `second()` like this.

```
@task()
def second(dummy):
    ...

third(second(first()))
```